# How To Logout a Google User in my Android Application on Button Click In Java?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, scribe

I have been successful at Login in a user (asking for their approval and then letting them do some other protected stuff) and now I want to clear their login or in other words, Log them out when they click a button.

Is there a path that I could load a webview? I know other sites have something like https://somewebsite.com/logout which logs people out.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out a way to clear everything. 
I hope someone else finds it useful!

```
public void clearCookies(){
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(GooglePlusActivity.this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this - cookieManager.removeAllCookie(); remove all cookies, not just the google ones?

Answer (score 1):

Follow [these Android signout instructions on the Google+ developer site](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#sign_out_the_user) to sign out the user and let them switch accounts or be logged out.

Comment: I figured out a way to remove all cookies using a sync manager. Thanks for the suggestion.